# What FTP libraries come with the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, api, ftp

What FTP libraries come with .NET?

Answer (score 7):

The only one that I know about that is included in the Base Class Library are the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) / [`FtpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx) classes. MSDN also features [some tutorials on how to use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx). Note though that they are not supported by the .NET Compact Framework (in case you plan on making a Windows Mobile application).

Answer (score 3):

- FTP is with FtpWebRequest
- FTPS (FTP over SSL) is with FtpWebRequest by setting `request.EnableSsl = true;`
- SFTP (SSH file transfer) is not and will require a third party library such as SharpSSH  - which is opensource.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.FtpWebRequest

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx